# Decoupling capacitor selection criteria for this multi-IC system

Tags: power, led-strip, decoupling-capacitor

How can I select the decoupling capacitor values? I know the rule of thumb is 0.1 μF per V<sub>DD</sub> pin, but how does this work with multiple types of ICs (or if it even matters)?

I'm trying to make a macro keyboard using a Seeeduino and an I/O expander (I know a matrix layout is industry standard, but I just wanted to learn how I/O expanders work and figured this was a decent way to do it).

So I have the Seeeduino, a [CY8C9540A](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cypress-semiconductor-corp/CY8C9540A-24PVXI/1640247) 40-bit I/O expander, and 16 NeoPixels.

The [Arduino NeoPixel guide on Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/basic-connections) says 100-1000 μF for a string, or 0.1 μF per LED. So can I just use a single 100 μF for the whole board?

This is what I have as of now, but it feels... wrong

[image]

Can I get away with this, or do I really need individual capacitors for each, and ones for the Seeeduino and I/O expander as well?

Here's the schematic as of now:

[image]

I know the expander is overkill, but the 20-bit version is out of stock. Also  I have yet to actually connect the data pins for the switches, and the DIN for the LEDs.

Comment: LEDs don't care about decoupling. It's just light. if it hiccups no one cares and your eyes are too slow to detect it anyways. But a processor and logic circuits are a different story and every little trace is an inductor so you can't replace a bunch of small decoupling capacitors into one big one.

Comment: Generally, the exact value of decoupling capacitors isn't critical. It can be in some situations, but for the vast majority of purposes, all that you really need is to slap some capacitance on there, ideally close to the pin. Sometimes, the datasheet will tell you a specific value to use (or a range, or a minimum), and you should use that.

Comment: @DKNguyen My understanding is that these "neopixels" are more than just LEDs; they're RGB LEDs with a small microcontroller and driver to allow them to be individually controlled in a daisy chain fashion. So they may well need decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @Hearth Yes if that is the case then they would be safest with individual decoupling.

Comment: @DKNguyen I agree; but those are not just LEDs, they are modules with integrated chip with data IO and PWM driver for RGB LEDs.

Comment: The guide you link to tries to say you should have a 100-1000 uF bulk decoupling capacitor at the point where power enters your board AND 100nF decoupling for each trough hole neo-pixel. (I'm assuming they think if you have SMD neo-pixels it is on a premade strip which comes with decoupling caps on the strip).

Comment: I have always used 1 uF ceramic multilayer capacitors for bypass, and often several ICs per capacitor. Why 1 uF? I had several thousand thru-hole parts from surplus, and I bought the equivalent SMD parts for cheap in 1000 pc quantity. But that was for relatively low speed TTL, CMOS, and PIC circuits. Components like MOSFET drivers, 100 MHz+ processors, and switching controllers need more care.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each Neopixel is basically an IC.

So each IC should have a 100nF cap right at the supply pins. Unless told otherwise.

A single large capacitor far away from ICs is not helpful for many reasons.

Answer (score 10):

Read the note just below the one you refer to on the webpage you linked:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's part of why I was confused because it says that but further up shows a circuit with a 1000uF cap and a strip.

Comment: @JacksonV The difference is low vs high frequency decoupling. SInce every trace is an inductor high frequency decoupling needs to be as close to the IC as possible. High frequencies voltage dips tend to involve less energy than low frequency which is good because small value caps tend towards the least parasitic inductance. Low frequencies involve tend to involve larger energies so need larger caps but since it's low frequency it can be farther away because the trace inductance has less of an effect. The bulk low freq decoupling C isn't necessarily the sum of the high freq decoupling C.

Comment: And if you need to decouple high frequencies that carry lots of energy...that's when things get hairy.

Comment: "Yeah that's part of why I was confused because it says that but further up shows a circuit with a 1000uF cap and a strip". That makes sense. The red box says use a 1000uF cap, which they did, and the orange box says use a 0.1uF cap on each pixel and that strips have those built in, so they used a strip and didn't need to add any.

Answer (score 7):

Also of note: use a ground plane design, preferring component placement and trace routing on top side, with minimal jumps to the bottom side, which is filled with GND.  (Using a few extra vias to route like this is no problem: vias are cheap; EMI problems are cursed!)  Top can be filled as well, remember to use stitching vias to anchor any islands/peninsulas/trace crossings that result.

Bypass caps can be shared to some extent; it's okay to have one shared between a few adjacent chips, as long as the maximum distance from the furthest is within limits (for average CMOS logic these days, a few cm should be okay).

Prioritize larger chips: use one cap per set of power pins.  Basically just the IO expander here, as the -ino has onboard caps already.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what NeoPixel exactly you're using. Some datasheets got revised, specifying that a capacitor is not necessary. Below is an example: the datasheet for WS2812B-2020 (2020 refers to the package size, not year), capacitors were removed from the datasheet in the year 2019. **More importantly**, various kinds of NeoPixel-like LEDs are being used by many people successfully without capacitors even though the datasheets recommend capacitors.

If all datasheets for all packages of the chip you use recommend capacitors and you want to be on the safe side, you can use capacitors. In that case, one capacitor near each NeoPixel. As near as possible, with high capacitance, see "Habit 6" and "Habit 7" [here](https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/blogs/12-fundamentals/post/1207-seven-habits-of-successful-2-layer-board-designers).

[image]